# Is it possible to customise checkout liquid with an App

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I bought a shopify plus to customise my checkout page -add some html and JS to the checkout template-  and I read this in the shopify documentation :

If you're on Shopify Plus, then you can edit the code for your checkout. However, if you make changes to your checkout code, then you need to upgrade your checkout.liquid template manually whenever Shopify makes an upgrade.

and I was wondering If it's possible to create an App to do that for me.

I mean :

1-Create an app to modify the checkout page.

2-After each update my app modify it automatically or at least I just re install my app and the checkout will be updated.

I already have shopify plus and managed to do that by modifying the checkout.liquid.

But It's not really an efficient way to change the checkout.liquid each time might be ok for one user but what if I want to do the same for a lot of shopify users for example.

It's a Basic concept making a plugin in other ecommerce platforms such as Prestashop, Magento ... But It seems really complicated in Shopify.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you're on Shopify Plus, then you can edit the code for your
>   checkout. However, if you make changes to your checkout code, then you
>   need to upgrade your checkout.liquid template manually whenever
>   Shopify makes an upgrade.

This statement means that whenever Shopify introduces some changes on their end in the Checkout process they will notify you prior to update. 30 days prior as far as I know so that you can update and test. They will provide you details for changelog so that you can verify if it does break any of your customizations. Such changes are not frequenet and I cannot think of any automated way that your app will be able to analyze the changelog and decide if it affects your customizarions or not.

Since most of your changes will be in additional JavaScript it won't be much of an effort for you and will not be as frequent.

However, if you manage many stores for multiple Shopify plus customers then you may push an update manually to all stores that have your APP installed and make use of Assets API to modify **checkout.liquid** file.

For example, if Shopify notifies you that Checkout code is changed and you need to update it. Just review the changelog, then initiate a process on your APP backend that updates the new code to all chekout.liquid files on all the stores where your app is installed.

[Assets API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/asset)

[Checkout Customization](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/layouts/checkout)

Comment: Thanks for your help I just noticed your reply and this is exactly what I did to solve this.